# How to convert a string to unicode/byte string in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encode, codec

I know this works:

```
a = u"\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"
print(a) # 方法，删除存储在
```

But if I have a string from a JSON file which does not start with "u"(`a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"`), I know how to make it in Python 2 (`print unicode(a, encoding='unicode_escape') # Prints 方法，删除存储在`). But how to do it with Python 3?

Similarly, if it's a byte string loaded from a file, how to convert it?

```
print("好的".encode("utf-8"))  # b'\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe7\x9a\x84'
# how to convert this?
b = '\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe7\x9a\x84'  # 好的
```

Comment: Python 3 uses unicode as default, therefore just `print(a)` (your console should support unicode).  To convert byte string to unicode in Python 3, use `str(b, 'utf-8')`.  To test your code, use IDLE (Python shell) which supports unicode.

Comment: @Lex: Are you saying the file itself contains the literal text `\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for pointing that out, I removed my comment after you corrected my answer. Again, unaware how vast the change is between python2 vs python 3

Comment: @acw1668  `print(str("\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe7\x9a\x84","utf-8"))` raise a error :"TypeError: decoding str is not supported",

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, it's a json unicode text, I made it  use `print(json.loads('"{}"'.format(b)))`, but it looks weird, if I have a very long json string and the json format is not quite right ,this method may be not work

Comment: @Lex your input to `print(str(...))` is not a byte string.  Please try: `print(str(b"\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe7\x9a\x84", "utf-8"))`.

Comment: @acw1668 I can't write this string directly, "\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe7\x9a\x84" is load from a file and sign to "b", it's dynamic

Comment: @Lex you can convert the string to byte string first: `bs = bytes(b,'latin')`, then `print(str(bs,'utf-8'))`.

Comment: @acw1668 it works! thank you very much!  

but this "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728" I can't find a good way convert it, there is a similar way to do that ?

Comment: @Lex As I said before that Python 3 uses unicode as default, therefore you can just print the string.  If it does not work, then try converting the string to byte string: `bs = bytes(a, 'utf-8')` (assume `a = "\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728"`), then `print(str(bs,'utf-8'))`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the file contains the literal text `\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728` (so it's plain ASCII, but with backslashes and all that describe the Unicode ordinals the same way you would in a Python `str` literal). If so, there are two ways to handle this:

1. Read the file in binary mode, then call `mystr = mybytes.decode('unicode-escape')` to convert from the `bytes` to `str` interpreting the escapes
2. Read the file in text mode, and use the `codecs` module for the "text -> text" conversion (bytes to bytes and text to text codecs are now supported only by the `codecs` module functions; `bytes.decode` is purely for bytes to text and `str.encode` is purely for text to bytes, because usually, in Py2, `str.encode` and `unicode.decode` was a mistake, and removing the dangerous methods makes it easier to understand what direction the conversions are supposed to go), e.g. `decodedstr = codecs.decode(encodedstr, 'unicode-escape')`

Comment: Not the OP but I tried reading from a file in binary mode that had one line `\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe7\x9a\x84`. This gave me `b'\\xe5\\xa5\\xbd\\xe7\\x9a\\x84'` and printing that with `.decode('unicode-escape')` gives `å¥½ç` ... and not `'好的'` as expected by OP

Comment: the string `\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728` in file is loaded from a http request, it's a json unicode string, I tried the code `print(codecs.decode("'\u65b9\u6cd5\uff0c\u5220\u9664\u5b58\u50a8\u5728'", 'unicode-escape'))`,  it prints 'æ¹æ³ï¼å é¤å­å¨å¨', not  '好的'